# Calling external applications/bat files using QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to execute/call an external application in Windows or a batch file (bat) using the QGIS Graphic Modeller? I am using QGIS version 3.28.7

Comment: Since a processing tool, so a graphic modeler element can be written in Python, you can call `subprocess.run` : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a [processing script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) that calls the bat/sh/exe using the [`subprocess` python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

[image]

E.g. a simple processing script that takes one input, a CSV file, passes it to an external batch file and captures the output of the batch file (the number of lines in the input CSV) and returns that:

```
from qgis.processing import alg
import subprocess

@alg(name="shellscript", label=alg.tr("shellscript"), group='examplescripts', group_label='Example scripts')
@alg.input(type=alg.FILE, name="CSV_INPUT", label="CSV File")
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name='OUTPUTFEATURES', label='Number of features processed')
def shellscript(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this doc string will cause errors.)"""

    output = subprocess.check_output(["/path/to/test.bat", parameters["CSV_INPUT"]])

    return {'OUTPUTFEATURES': int(output)}
```

This processing script can then be added to a model:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @user2856 exactly what I needed. Never tried it but time to learn something new.